# How to add 0 for months that has no sales?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array:

```
  let sales=  [
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 3 }, total_sales: 1800 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 4 }, total_sales: 5700 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 5 }, total_sales: 6630 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 6 }, total_sales: 690 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 7 }, total_sales: 1600 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 8 }, total_sales: 13430 }
     ]
```

What I'm trying to do is, convert to months to names by

```
            let months = []
            let sales = []
            var m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

            for (let i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
                if (sales.length === 6) {
                    var monthName = m[sales[i]._id.month - 1]
                    months.push(monthName)
                    sales.push(sales[i].total_sales)
                }
            }
```

returns the following as expected.

```
["March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"] 
[1800, 5700, 6630, 690, 1600, 13430]
```

However, If I have a month missing in the array, how can I rearrange it to show `total_sales=0` with monthname.

Show case:

```
 [
       { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12 }, total_sales: 1800 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 1 }, total_sales: 5700 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 2 }, total_sales: 6630 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 4 }, total_sales: 690 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 6 }, total_sales: 1600 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 8 }, total_sales: 13430 }
     ]
```

Expected result:

```
["August","September","October","November",
"December","January","February","March", "April", 
"May", "June", "July", "August"] 

[0, 0, 0, 0, 1800, 5700, 6630, 0, 690, 0, 1600, 0, 13430]

Every 12 month period.
```

Comment: what value comes in loop for this.props.salesGraph.sales

Comment: As your input data is in ascending order, just iterate the current array and push if the next occuring month is not the next month in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     let stats=  [
           { _id: { year: 2020, month: 3 }, total_sales: 1800 },
           { _id: { year: 2020, month: 4 }, total_sales: 5700 },
           { _id: { year: 2020, month: 5 }, total_sales: 6630 },
           { _id: { year: 2020, month: 6 }, total_sales: 690 },
           { _id: { year: 2020, month: 7 }, total_sales: 1600 },
           { _id: { year: 2020, month: 8 }, total_sales: 13430 }
         ]

   let monthsNumber = []

            for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            //Past 6 months 
                let currentDate = new Date()
                let currentMonth = currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() - i)
                var newDate = new Date(currentMonth)
                monthsNumber.unshift(newDate.getMonth() + 1)
            }


            let sales = []
            let months = []
            var m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

            let stats = this.props.salesGraph.sales

            monthsNumber.forEach(value => {
                var monthName = m[value - 1];
                months.push(monthName);
            })

            let allStats = stats.map(eachStat => {
                return {
                    month: eachStat._id.month,
                    total_sales: eachStat.total_sales
                }
            })

            for (let i = 0; i < monthsNumber.length; i++) {
                let index = allStats.findIndex(eachStat => eachStat.month === monthsNumber[i])
                if (index !== -1) {
                    sales.push(allStats[index].total_sales)
                } else {
                    sales.push(0)
                }
            }
```

response:

```
[1800, 0, 12330, 690, 1600, 13430]
["March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the below

```
    let months = []
    let sales = []
    var m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    
    const firstEntry = this.props.salesGraph.sales[0]._id;
    
    const startMonth = firstEntry.year*12+firstEntry.month;
    const lastIteratedMonth = startMonth-1;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.salesGraph.sales.length; i++) {
        let currentEntry = this.props.salesGraph.sales[i]._id;
        let currentMonth = currentEntry.year*12+currentEntry.month;
        while(lastIteratedMonth+1 < currentMonth) {
            //Fill missing months with 0
            var monthName = m[lastIteratedMonth%12-1];
            months.push(monthName);
            sales.push(0);
            lastIteratedMonth++;
        }
        let monthName = m[currentEntry.month - 1];
        months.push(monthName);
        sales.push(this.props.salesGraph.sales[i].total_sales);
        lastIteratedMonth++;
    }
```

Comment: you sales array returns undefined for all values thats pushed into the array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var sales = [
       { _id: { year: 2019, month: 12 }, total_sales: 1800 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 1 }, total_sales: 5700 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 2 }, total_sales: 6630 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 4 }, total_sales: 690 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 6 }, total_sales: 1600 },
       { _id: { year: 2020, month: 8 }, total_sales: 13430 }
];


var monthName = [
      '',
      'JANUARY',
      'FEBRUARY',
      'MARCH',
      'APRIL',
      'MAY',
      'JUNE',
      'JULY',
      'AUGUST',
      'SEPTEMBER',
      'OCTOBER',
      'NOVEMBER',
      'DECEMBER'
];

function getChartData() {
      var latestMonth = sales[sales.length-1]._id.month;
      var monthWiseSales = {};
      var months = [];
      var totalSales = [];
      
      sales.forEach(sale => {
          monthWiseSales[sale._id.month] = sale.total_sales;
      });
      
      var i = latestMonth;
      do {
          months.push(monthName[i]);
          totalSales.push(monthWiseSales[i] || 0);
          i = i === 1 ? 12 : i-1;
      } while(i != latestMonth);
      months.push(monthName[i]);
      totalSales.push(0);
      
      months.reverse();
      totalSales.reverse();
      
      console.log(months);
      console.log(totalSales);
}

getChartData();
```